# Generalized handling of SQL transaction failures due to isolation level serializable

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, isolation-level

The [PostgreSQL documentation 13.2.3. Serializable Isolation Level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) states:

> It is important that an environment which uses this technique have a generalized way of handling serialization failures (which always return with a SQLSTATE value of '40001'), because it will be very hard to predict exactly which transactions might contribute to the read/write dependencies and need to be rolled back to prevent serialization anomalies.

Is this as simple as always immediately retrying the transaction until it succeeds? Pseudocode:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        ...
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    }
    catch (SQLSTATE == '40001') {
        continue; // retry
    }
    break; // succeed
}
```

Is it guaranteed to succeed at some point? Are there situations where it's impossible that this will ever succeed after failing once? What else can / should one do? Does it depend on the scenario? Maybe sometimes earlier query transactions must be repeated too? In that case, how is a generalized solution possible?

Are there any open source examples of such a generalized handling mechanism? Or any good resources (books, articles, ...) describing different approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sample shows exactly how it should be done.

Serialization failures should happen rarely; if they don't, something in your database or application design is unsound.

I guess it it possible to construct a scenario where a transaction can never succeed, but that is no problem in practice.

Comment: Do you know any open source code examples that demonstrate this?

Comment: Do you know a different example? Or is nobody using this?